# How to Fix Error 1053 : The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-services, regedit

I created a very simple 2-line Python program, then I made it into an executable file :

```
print("Hello World!")
input("Press a key to exit.")
```

Then I created a windows service called 'hello' linked to this .exe file. The problem is that, when I try to start the service, it starts, but halfway through loading, this error appears 'Error 1053 : The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion'.

I've already tried this on regedit with the 180000, but it didn't work. Apparently the problem comes from a debug mode, but I don't understand it at all.

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that when Windows starts the service it escpect a return code of success of failure. Since you have `input()` as your last line of code the python process is waiting for user input, thus not finalizing and not sending any return code.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. I removed the input and I start all over again, and it still doesn't work. I honestly find it hard to understand...